# FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize freeze my app in iOS but no error appears

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin with C#.

`FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);`

^ this code works fine in my Android `Application.cs` file, I can receive notifications in Android. However, when I add this code to `AppDelegate.cs` in iOS, it freezes my app, meaning there's no response when I click on button or input field. But if I remove this line of code, my iOS app works.

I've Googled a lot but didn't get any luck, can someone please help me?

Following is my AppDelegate.cs code:

```
 public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        ServicePointManager
            .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        var iosClientHandler = new NSUrlSessionHandler();
      
        Services.HttpClientService.HttpClientHandler = iosClientHandler;

        LoadApplication(new App());
        
        //This line is causing the issue
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
    }

    public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
    {
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);
    }

    // To receive notifications in foreground on iOS 9 and below
    // To receive notifications in background in any iOS version
    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired 'till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

        // If you disable method swizzling, you'll need to call this method.
        // This lets FCM track message delivery and analytics, which is performed
        // automatically with method swizzling enabled
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        // Do your magic to handle the notification data
        System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
    }
}
```